# Permissions required to get Azure Application using same application's client id and secret

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

Steps I have performed,

1. Create Azure Application

   - Created an Azure Application
   - Created a secret
   - Created a service principal
     Note: I have not added any extra permissions or consent.
2. Get Application Token using "Client Credential Flow" (ClientId and ClientSecret)

**ObjectId** used in below request is same application that I have created above.

3. **GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/%7B){objectId}}**

   - I able to get "Azure Application".

But, as per the documentation [GET Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), I need atleast "Application.Read.All" permission to get application.

Similarly,
4. **GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/%7B){objectId}}**
- I able to get "Service Principal".

But, as per the documentation [GET ServicePrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), I need atleast "Application.Read.All" permission to get application.

**Question** 
Is this an expected behavior, that I am able to fetch my own Azure Application, without any additional permissions. Or it's some bug. As I am not able to find any documentation backing this up.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Comment: I have raised the same question on "Microsoft Q&A". They have added comments about the behavior in respective documents. References:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/15880
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/15879

Answer (score 0):

***If you generate the access token using the application that you created and then search for the same application using objectId and the service principal associated with it using service principal objectId , then you won't require any kind of other permission i.e. `Application.Read.All/Directory.Read.All` as you are using the same application's access token to find the details of app. But When you are using that access token to search other application present in your Active directory then you will definitely require one of the permission which is mentioned in the Documentation as well as it doesn't have permission to access the directory or other app's.***

**Example:**

**Created an App registration named Test with not granting any other permissions except which was present in default :**

[image]

[image]

**Using Client Credentials flow tried to search the same application object ID and Service principal object id for which I generated the token:**

[image]

[image]

**But using the same access token if I try to find other App like below then it errors out :**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am observing the same behavior and the fact that we are able to get fetch application and service principal details using same application's client id and client secret would make sense. But is there any official documentation present that would support this behaviour?

Comment: @AADITYARANE, This is an expected behaviour .. as why would an application need permission to see its own manifest/details. Unfortunately, no documentation is there to support this .